# Ionic/Cordova project Cannot find module q when building android side

Tags: android, cordova, command-line-interface, ionic-framework

I'm new to posting questions so excuse any Faux pas.

The issue I'm having occurs when using the command "ionic build android" or "Cordova build android" on my Ionic project. Also Visual studio was NOT involved in the creation process. I bring this up because the only other places I seem to find the "cannot find module q" error is with people using Visual Studio for their cross-platform project.

The project was created, both iOS and android platforms added and the plugins we needed were all added on my Macbook. The Macbook has the fully updated android SDK and Android Studio installed. All commands including "ionic build android" work on my Macbook. The problem arises when the project is cloned onto a different machine (windows or mac) and attempt to use "ionic build android". The other windows and mac machines I've tried also have the fully updated Android SDK.

All other commands work on the different machines expect for "ionic build android" or "ionic run android" since it uses build inside of it. I don't have the exact output but what seems to happen is that the part of the build commands that prepares the project works since the output for "ionic prepare android" can be seen before I get the "Cannot find module q" error.

What I've tried so far has been to remove and re-add the android platform but the only way I can do that is on my Macbook since it is portable and I need to go to an open access point in order to have internet access to the resources Ionic/Cordova needs to add the platform. I did try this once to see if it would make a difference and it didn't. It would take some doing but perhaps this would be fixed by removing and re-adding the platform using a different computer.

I've tried using NPM to download the "q" module to fill the reference it needs but that didn't seem to make a difference either.

Currently, I just use "ionic prepare android" and then use Eclipse to clean and build the project that way which works fine as a workaround for this.

It would take some doing but I can post the exact output I'm getting but I don't think it would reveal much. I can confidently say that it is breaking at the "Q = require("q");" statement.

If anyone has any advice or has dealt with this before and has a solution that would be great to know. It hasn't been a pressing issue but it has come up a number of time from people within my organization that clone the project and then attempt to use build command.

Currently using Ionic 1.0.0-beta.14 and Cordova version 3.5.0.

Comment: I'm building & running cordova android apps on my Mac and everyting works perfectly. When I switch to ubuntu, every cordova command works fine except `cordova build` and at this command I'm stuck, nothing happens and it never finishes. At the moment, I didn't a solution :(